# how to stop continuous scanning of QR code?

Tags: java, android, zxing, zbar

**this is my code, i want is after a scan for the first-time callApi() method should call, but it keep on scanning **

```
  @Override
public void handleResult(Result result) {

    System.out.print("BAR_CODE  "+ result.getContents());
    System.out.print("BAR_CODEE  "+result.getBarcodeFormat().getName());
    barcode_number = result.getContents();
    productcode.setText(result.getContents());

    //resume Camera
    scanner_bar.resumeCameraPreview(this);

    dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    dialog.setTitle("Loading");
    dialog.show();

    //callApi
    if(barcode_number != "") {

        callApi(barcode_number);
    }

};
```

Comment: you need to pause or stop your camera preview.

Comment: @Zaheer can you add zbar Gradle or github link

Comment: @Zaheer I am using zxing scanner on my App , if you want  it then i can assist you to implement this .

Comment: I used zxing before but it scans very slow, @Abhishekkumar

Comment: @MilanPansuriya https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner. github link

Comment: @zaheer check my answer.

Comment: @SaurabhBhandari  thank you sir, it worked for me. scanner_bar.stopCamera()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just replace your code with this

```
    @Override
public void handleResult(Result result) {

    System.out.print("BAR_CODE  "+ result.getContents());
    System.out.print("BAR_CODEE  "+result.getBarcodeFormat().getName());
    barcode_number = result.getContents();
    productcode.setText(result.getContents());

    //resume Camera
    scanner_bar.resumeCameraPreview(this);

    dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    dialog.setTitle("Loading");
    dialog.show();

    //callApi
    if(barcode_number != "") {
        scanner_bar.stopCamera(); 
        callApi(barcode_number);
    }

};
```

Comment: thank you sir it fixed by replacing   scanner_bar.resumeCameraPreview(this);        
 with         scanner_bar.stopCamera();

Comment: @zaheer your welcome plz accept and upvote my answer.